# Excel function to get dates between two columns and checking for unique values in Column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, days

I'm trying to find a formula to look up the NETWORKDAYS between four columns.

In column B I have Surnames; in column C I have First Names. I have a STARTDATE in column F and an end date in column in column I.

I'm aware of the NETWORKDAYS.INTL function; however in this case I need to be able to determine a TOTAL between column F and column I in the event that I have the same person listed in column B/C. Is there a LOOKUP function or something I could use?

**I need to know what the TOTAL number of days there are in the event that there are multiple start/end dates due to multiple instances of the same person in columns B & C.**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you provide a representative set of data that demonstrates the problem you are having, along with the code/functions you are using, the results you are getting, and the results you desire. Perhaps reading HELP for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), will help you edit your question so as to express your problem better.

Comment: You should post the expected output too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula below which check for duplicate names and sums the Days to deliver 1 course

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$7&$C$2:$C$7=B2&C2),$J$2:$J$7)
```

Where B & C are name columns and J is days for 1 course